# ¿Cómo se llama la rama de la lingüística que estudia la entonación?

Tags: pronunciación, lingüística, fonología

El tono en el que se transmite un mensaje en cualquier lengua, también el español, influye tremendamente en lo que se pretende transmitir.
Un simple "¿Qué?", en función de la entonación puede variar trementamente. Algunos ejemplos sobre la entonación del "¿Qué?" podrían ser:

- ¿Qué has dicho? que no te he entendido.
- ¿Quieres pelea?

La pregunta es cómo se llama la rama de la lingüística que estudia la entonación. No es la fonética ni cuestión de acentos, es el tono. ¿Existe esa rama? Si existe ¿alguien sabe cómo se llama?

Answer (score 4):

Parece que la **fonología** estudia, entre otras cosas, la entonación. Según el DLE, la [fonología](https://dle.rae.es/fonolog%C3%ADa) es:

> 1. f. Ling. Parte de la gramática que estudia cómo se estructuran los sonidos y los elementos suprasegmentales de una lengua para transmitir significados

y [suprasegmental](https://dle.rae.es/suprasegmental) significa:

> 1. adj. Fon. Dicho de un elemento fónico: Que afecta a más de un fonema, como el acento, la entonación o el ritmo.

Wikipedia también dice que la [fonología](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa) estudia

> ... las sílabas, la entonación, la acentuación, etc.

Comment: En efecto, en mis épocas de estudiante estudiábamos los sonidos en fonética y la entonación en fonología.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que específicamente estás buscando es la **pragmática**. Viendo la otra respuesta y de acuerdo a mi entender, la fonología estudia patrones, reglas y convenciones de pronunciación bajo un tratamiento general, digamos que lo que *se transmite* a nivel 'teórico'. Mientras que la pragmática estudia justamente el lenguaje en diversas situaciones específicas y prácticas, digamos que estudia lo que *se pretende transmitir*.

Obviamente que tal disciplina es enorme y hay un montón de problemas que los ha tomado como objeto de estudio. No soy un especialista pero, con lo que sé, si querés iniciarte en el tema te sugeriría que empecés leyendo *Introducción a la Pragmática* de Escandell Vidal. En particular en la sección 3 del capítulo 3 se menciona la tricotomía de Austin (distinción entre actos locutivos, ilocutivos y perlocutivos), la misma es un ejemplo de un análisis que está relacionado con lo que estás preguntando.

> Constantemente discutimos preguntando si ciertas palabras—un determinado acto locutivo—tenían la fuerza de una pregunta, o debían haber sido tomadas como una apreciación, etc. [Austin, 1962: 143-144]

Answer (score 1):

Hay una disciplina de la gramática que se llama [**Prosodia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosodia_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)) que estudia la entonación y en general toda la producción "física" de las palabras y las frases. No diría que es una "rama" sino más bien una perspectiva de análisis, paralela a otras disciplinas gramaticales como la morfología, la sintaxis y la gramática diacrónica.

En todo caso, la entonación es parte del estudio de varias ramas de la lingüística, no solo la gramática, porque afecta prácticamente todos los niveles de análisis del lenguaje.

Lo más obvio sería responder que la estudia la **fonología**, porque la entonación es propiamente un fenómeno acústico. Pero esa variación tiene su causa y efectos en las intenciones comunicativas, por lo que también es un importante objeto de estudio de la **pragmalingüística** (*cómo logro mis objetivos modificando la entonación de mis palabras*) y la **sociolingüística** (*cómo muestro mi pertenecia a un grupo adoptando su entonación*). E incluso hay idiomas (llamados "lenguas tonales") en los que la entonación afecta la **semántica**, vale decir el significado puro y duro de las palabras.